# Как проверить, запущен ли Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Когда мое приложение запускается в onCreate() я запускаю метод:

```
private void startNotifyService() {

        Calendar timeNotification = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeNotification.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        timeNotification.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        timeNotification.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // если заданное время меньше текущего, то к нему прибовляется один день
        if (timeNotification.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            timeNotification.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        if (am != null)
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeNotification.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Все исправно работает и каждый день в 12 часов срабатывает AlarmManager.

Подскажите, как сделать проверку, установлен ли уже Alarm?

Или есть другой способ, что бы ни устанавливать его каждый раз при запуске приложения.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно проверить, установлен ли AlarmManager:

На [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin):

```
fun isAlarmSet(context: Context): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
    return pendingIntent != null
}
```

На [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
public static boolean isAlarmSet(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    return pendingIntent != null;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если приложение останавливали (force stop, terminate), `alarm` сбросится, а `pendingIntent` продолжит существовать. То есть функция даст некорректное состояние. Сталкивались с таким?